# Java GPA calculator/take all grade strings in order to create final gpa/Scanner/String

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I've been having trouble with this problem in which:

Whenever I input a series of string letters, it simply lists 0.0 as the gpa, when it should vary.

When I input B B C B F into the program,
it inputs your GPA is 0.0, although it should be at least higher than 2.0

I have to 
write a program that accepts the letter grades for a student, 
calculates the student's gpa, 
and prints it out,
along with one of the following five messages:

**Eligible.
Ineligible, taking less than 4 classes.
Ineligible, gpa below 2.0.
Ineligible, gpa above 2.0 but has F grade (note: gpa >= 2.0).
Ineligible, gpa below 2.0 and has F grade.**

The message "Ineligible, taking less than 4 classes" has priority over the other 3 ineligible cases.

The class will not ask the user for how many grades are in a student's report 
card.

The program will continue to read grades until a non-grade character is input.

At this point, some type of loop will cease and the program prints the GPA value and the eligibility message.

Example of run output:        GPA = 3.75        Eligible

I do not have to print out any of the individual grades.

so far I have gotten this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
public class P4_Icel_Murad_totals
{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        double gpa = 0;
        double input = 0;
        String total = "";
        int classes = 0;
        boolean fail = false;
        do{
             Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter All class totals in letter form(type stop to stop): ");
            total = in.nextLine();
            total = total.toLowerCase();
            if(total.equals('a')){
                input = 4.0;
            }else if (total.equals('b')){
                input = 3.0;
            }else if (total.equals('c')){
                input = 2.0;
            }else if (total.equals('d')){
                input = 1.0;
            }else if (total.equals('f')){
               fail = true;
            }
            gpa += input;
            classes++;
        }while (!total.equals("stop"));
         System.out.println("Your GPA is: " + gpa + "   ");
         if (gpa >= 2  && classes >= 4 && fail == false){
             System.out.println("Eligible");
         }else if(classes < 4){
            System.out.println("Ineligible, taking less than 4 classes");
         }else if(gpa < 2.0 && fail == false && classes >= 4 ){
            System.out.println("Ineligible, gpa below 2.0");
         }else if(gpa >= 2.0 && fail != false && classes >= 4 ){
            System.out.println("Ineligible, gpa above 2.0 but has F grade (note: gpa >= 2.0");
         }else if(gpa < 2.0 && fail != false && classes >= 4 ){
            System.out.println("Ineligible, gpa below 2.0 and has F grade");
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Provide your exact input and your exact output. Your program seems to do exactly what you said it should, so it is most likely a problem with your input.

Comment: @Soana when I input B B C B F into the question, it gives me the gpa as 0.0 when thats clearly not the case

Comment: @Chriss Whenever I input a series of string letters, it simply lists 0.0 as the gpa, when it should vary

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel Have you tried entering 'b b c b f'?

EDIT: missed the `total = total.toLowerCase();` line

Comment: @RichardJones I did try both, I don't know why it still gives the gpa as 0 however

Comment: Are you entering `B <Enter> B <Enter> C <Enter> B <Enter> F` or `B B C B F <Enter>`?

Comment: @Soana I am doing the first one, however I have attempted both

Comment: Btw shouldn't the final score be divided by the number of classes taken?

Comment: @Soana I might have forgotten to add that lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are entering is "B B C B F" so when you are trying to with the individual letters you are essentially doing `if ("b b c b d".equals("a"))` etc.

To split the string you can use `.split(" ")`

`String grades[] = total.split(" ");`

will produce an array containing each letter. You will then need to loop over each one and add this to the gpa total.

```
total = total.toLowerCase();

String grades[] = total.split(" ");
for (String grade : grades){
    if (grade.equals("a")) {
        input = 4.0;
    } else if (grade.equals("b")) {
        input = 3.0;
    } else if (grade.equals("c")) {
        input = 2.0;
    } else if (grade.equals("d")) {
        input = 1.0;
    } else if (grade.equals("f")) {
         fail = true;
         input = 0.0; //needed as if it fails it will still add previous value onto total
    }
    gpa += input;
    classes++;
}
```

Comment: but I have attempted each of them seperately, such as B <Enter> B <Enter> C <Enter> B <Enter> F and it still gives me a 0.0

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel is was because you were using `'` instead of `"` in the equals function. `'` are used to assign chars, while `"` are used to assign strings

Comment: @RichardJones look at my answer, it explains the difference

Comment: @RichardJones  ok when I changed the quotes, it allowed the string to be recognized, however, when i put it in all of one string it still presents zero. But now when I put them in seperately, it says that the gpa is 11.0

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel have you split the string?

Comment: @RichardJones yes, but it still gives gpa as 11.0

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel Is your code the exact same as mine? As just tried it and it works fine. 

`Please enter All class totals in letter form(type stop to stop): b b c b f` 
`Please enter All class totals in letter form(type stop to stop): stop` 
`Your GPA is: 11.0`  
`Ineligible, gpa above 2.0 but has F grade (note: gpa >= 2.0`

Comment: @RichardJones yes exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

The current misbehaviour stems from the implementation of the `equals()`-method in `String`. From the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

What happens: The char literal becomes a Character object, when it is passed to `equals()`. A Character object is not an instance of `String`, so `equals()` returns `false` by design.